# Network onchange event is not getting triggered in case of wifi with exclamation mark in ionic3/5

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, ionic3

We have a usecase where in we are using the socket for the Live data to display it in our mobile app. We are using Microsoft signalR(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr)

When ever network disconnects (wifi off / mobile data off) the ionic network plugin's "network disconnect" callback method will be called and then we show the error message to the user on screen like "Socket disconnected. No internet." but in one usecase we are not getting the callback method i.e. when on the mobile device wifi is on but with the exclamation or cross mark on it. we dont get any callback event in this scenario to show the proper error message on the screen.

Comment: I don't know that NPM package but usually Network Events, like you're using, notices about Network Changes. If the WiFi becames connected the event is correct. If the INTERNET on that WiFi connection became unstable or you lost it, the WiFi connection doesn't changes, so no any Event could be triggered. You have to do a "ping" to some know Server to be sure if you still have Internet connection after any "Network Change" event...

Comment: Thanks @emandt . But how do i to "PING" to some know server if there is no internet?

Comment: Just try an HTTP request to a know/your Server by setting a timeout of 5 seconds. If there isn't any connection you will get a Timeout Error and you can presume there isnt' any internet connectivity available (even if WiFi is full of bars).

Comment: Can you share your code where you register a network callback along with the callback itself?

Comment: check this link `https://gist.github.com/sandy912`